# How to pass configs from blazor app to service worker

Tags: javascript, .net, service-worker, appsettings

I need to pass my configs from my appsettings.json to service worker. I have tried passing it after the service worker registration like this

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
            .then(registration => {
                registration.active.postMessage({ firebaseConfig: config });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Firebase Messaging Service Worker registration failed:', error);
            });
```

but this is called after the registration so I tried with install event and passing it with query params like this but in this case I am getting error

Event handler of 'push' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const configParam = new URL(location).searchParams.get('config');
            console.log(configParam);
            firebaseConfig = configParam ? JSON.parse(configParam) : null;
            resolve();
        })
    );
});
```

so how can I get the configs directly in my service worker?